# Abstract two functions from a single logic

Tags: apex

Here is my code, I know there must be something wrong since I cannot compile it. I just create two INSERT functions and try to use them in the 'createAppoint'. As you can see there are some logics I have to go through. Can anyone out there help me understand what's the specific mistakes I made here?

```
private static void createAppoint(){
    Opportunity opp = getConvertedOpp(oppId);
    if(opp.RecordType.DeveloperName == RecordTypeConstans.EFEC_B2C_CN_Opportunity){
        if(opp.School__c.contains('_TSC')){
            createEvent();
            createSalesAppt();
        }else{
            createSalesAppt();
        }
    }else if (opp.RecordType.DeveloperName == RecordTypeConstans.EFTS_B2C_CN_Opportunity) {
        createEvent();
    }else{
        createSalesAppt();
    }
}

public void createEvent(String oppId, Lead lead){
    Event event = new Event();
    String eventName = 'OB';
    event.Subject=eventName;
    event.Description=eventName;
    event.WhatId = oppId;
    event.StartDateTime = lead.Initial_Appt_Time__c;
    event.EndDateTime = lead.Initial_Appt_Time__c.addHours(1);
    event.Event_Appt_Status__c = PickListValuesCustom.Activity_Status_Scheduled;
    event.IsReminderSet = true;
    event.ReminderDateTime = event.StartDateTime.addMinutes(-15);
    insert event;
}

public void createSalesAppt(String oppId, String schoolName, Lead lead){
    Sales_Appointment__c appoint = new Sales_Appointment__c();
    appoint.Appointment_Time__c = lead.Initial_Appt_Time__c;
    appoint.Opportunity__c = oppId;
    appoint.Schedule_Times__c = 1;
    appoint.Center__c = CommonUtilities.getSchoolIdByName(schoolName);
    appoint.Status__c = PickListValuesCustom.SalesAppointment_Status_Scheduled;
    insert appoint;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Please [edit] the post to include the specific error messages and line numbers you are receiving.

Comment: @DavidReed thanks sir, the error message is like this:  Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void createEvent()

Basically all methods in the first function--createAppoint() are triggering this error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bits between the `()` in your function's definition are parameters (e.g. `(String oppId, Lead lead)`. They're absolutely required, so you can't skip them. The parameters must be in the right order, and of the correct type. Therefore, you'd have to do something more like:

```
if(opp.RecordType.DeveloperName == RecordTypeConstans.EFEC_B2C_CN_Opportunity){
    if(opp.School__c.contains('_TSC')){
        createEvent(opp.Id, ?...?);
    }
    createSalesAppt(opp.Id, opp.School__c, ?...?);
}else if (opp.RecordType.DeveloperName == RecordTypeConstans.EFTS_B2C_CN_Opportunity) {
    createEvent(opp.Id, ?...?);
}else{
    createSalesAppt(opp.Id, opp.School__c, ?...?);
}
```

The other part you're missing is the lead (`?...?`), so you'll need to get that from somewhere, presumably from the method calling this one.

The error "Method does not exist or incorrect signature" can mean either the function name is misspelled, or the number of parameters is incorrect, or one or more parameters are of the incorrect data type (or a compatible type).

Comment: thank you sir! I just realized this issue when I posted it! Without parameters, the method can never be executed...hh. thanks for your detailed explanation!